# fill div with image when text li is clicked

Tags: jquery, image, html, fill, click

I am learning the basics of jquery and have a question.

I have a client who wants her "friends" page to have a div that fills with a screenshot of her friend's site when the li link of the friend's name is clicked. This screenshot image will then function as a link to the respective website which will open in new window. The div will need to preload the first friends screenshot on the list so an image occupies the div when landing on the page.

How can I make the li link fill the div with a screenshot for each of the eight friends she wants to list?

Thanks so much for any advice.

Comment: Are you asking how to programmatically take a screen shot of a website or just how to show an image on a link mouseover?

Comment: To show image in a div when one clicks on the corresponding li text link for that friend.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/NDnsa/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Friend 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Friend 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Friend 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="view">
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://www.dummyimage.com/350x200/000/fff&text=friend1.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

**JS/JQUERY:**

```
var friendArr = [
    {
        url: "http://www.google.com",
        img: "http://www.dummyimage.com/350x200/000/fff&text=friend1.jpg"
    },
    {
        url: "http://www.yahoo.com",
        img: "http://www.dummyimage.com/350x200/cef/ff0&text=friend2.jpg"
    },
    {
        url: "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
        img: "http://www.dummyimage.com/350x200/f00/fff&text=friend3.jpg"
    }
];

$("#nav a").click(function() {
    var idx = $("#nav a").index(this);
    $("#view a").attr("href", friendArr[idx].url);
    $("#view a img").attr("src", friendArr[idx].img);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: that looks like it should work, thanks so much!

if I wanted the div image to show on hover of the link, would I just change the .click to .hover in this code?


    $("#nav a").click(function()

Comment: hover would work, but you would need a second function for the mouseout event `$().hover(function(){},function(){});` mouseover would work as a direct substitute `$().mouseover(function(){});`

Comment: Thank you for the help. Do I need to reference a jquery library for the code in the link above, or is this just simple javascript?

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @chad: Yes, you'll need jQuery.